# How to align terms in a vertically stacked equation?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, equations

I've been trying to figure out for the better part of two hours how I can vertically align terms and operators to give me an output that is akin to this picture:

[image]

Any help you might be able to provide would be much appreciated.

Comment: With the `align` environment (ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) from the `amsmath` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good `array` can make some input work for us:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{c@{{}={}}*5{c@{{}+{}}}c}
S&1&2&3&\ldots&(n-1)&n\\[6pt]
S&n&(n-1)&\ldots&3&2&1
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You did it!  That's great, I really appreciate it!  :)

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to have the content form part of the regular suite of [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) `align`-and-friends, you can set the respective terms in similar-sized boxes that are centre-aligned. This is easily achieved using [`eqparbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox)'s `\eqmakebox[<tag>]{<stuff>}`, setting all boxes have the same `<tag>` with the same width:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,eqparbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  S &= \eqmakebox[t1]{$1$} + \eqmakebox[t2]{$2$} + \eqmakebox[t3]{$3$} 
       + \eqmakebox[t3]{$\cdots$} + \eqmakebox[t2]{$(n-1)$} + \eqmakebox[t1]{$n$} \\
  S &= \eqmakebox[t1]{$n$} + \eqmakebox[t2]{$(n-1)$} + \eqmakebox[t3]{$\cdots$} 
       + \eqmakebox[t3]{$3$} + \eqmakebox[t2]{$2$} + \eqmakebox[t1]{$1$}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would  rather use `align*`, if only, because it seems to be young Gauss' method of obtaining the sum of arithmetic progression.